# How do I style forms using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style my form for my coming soon page. Im trying to stick with only using CSS, HTML, JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT. Im wondering how I would go about doing something like this.
![enter image description here][1]

You can find the site here:
http://www.learnstreet.com/

Thanks In advance guys!

P.S Sorry I couldn't post an image aswell, reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: What do you got so far ?

Comment: Is there a technical question here?  View source on the url you linked , that will give you a idea on how to go about it.

Comment: @Lokase Yes, I have looked at the source code. But Im still not sure how to change the width of the actual input form part or how to get the curved corners.

Comment: Keep in mind that css is browser specific.   Viewing the link in IE gives a very different look than viewing it in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add css to the form like you would a normal object. If you want it to have pretext and rounded corners then you could use a background image such.

This is the input.

```
<input style="border:0;" size="42" type="text" name="subemail" value="Enter your pretext here."/>
```

This is an image as a submit button.

```
<input type="image" src="image source here" height="53" width="100" border="0" />
```

Then you can put all this inside a div with either rounded edges using css border radius,

```
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

Comment: Hey Thanks I was about to answer my own question but can't (lack of rep) but penny-patrol also helped. Thanks. =D

Answer (score 0):

here is a little fiddle on how to style element from javascript (the example generate them too) it doesn't look exactly what you are after but should illustrate how to style form element from javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/W7Vua/

Edited: Bit too late as already an accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Ive got it now but I guess everything helps. =D